# Trouble using Vue 3 Leaflet Marker Cluster POC

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vuejs3, leaflet.markercluster

I tried to implement markercluster function from this solution:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-leaflet-marker-cluster-poc-fweeu?file=/components/TestMap.vue

in my vue 3 project.

The groups of elements are showing when loaded, but as I try to click on a group, zoom in or change position on the map i get this error in console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat') LngBounds.js:192"

[Screenshot of what is displayed on app when loaded][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxaA4.png

[Screenschot of error message in console][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKwZV.png

This is a part of the index code in the vue module that contains the page that shows the map:

```
<marker-cluster :options="{ showCoverageOnHover: false, chunkedLoading: true }">
            
            <!--Pin for alle klubber-->
                <l-marker v-for="club in clubs" :key="club.name" class="clubMarker" :lat-lng="[club.latitude, club.longitude]" 
                @click="showClubPopup(club.latitude, club.longitude, club.orgName, (club.adr1+' '+club.adr2))">
                    <l-icon
                        :id="club.name"
                        :icon-anchor="[13,40]"
                        icon-url="src/assets/svg/club_pin.svg" >
                    </l-icon>
                </l-marker>
            
            </marker-cluster>
```

The `<marker-cluster>` object is a copy of the MarkerCluster.vue object the codesandbox link.
I am using these npm packages in the vue project:

```
"axios": "^1.3.5",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
"node.js": "^0.0.1-security",
"npm": "^9.6.5",
"patch-package": "^7.0.0",
"vue": "^3.2.47",
"vue-router": "^4.1.6",
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.1",
"@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1",
"@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
"leaflet": "^1.9.3",
"vite": "^4.1.0"
```

I do not know much about the markercluster package, so please help if you know the cause of this problem.